# How to get a percent in SSRS Matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, matrix, reporting-services

I'm pretty new to coding in SQL and using SSRS so I don't know if this should really be fixed in my query or if there is an easy answer on the SSRS side. I have a simple query that I've put into SSRS and added a Matrix to see the data. In the final "Total" row I'm trying to throw in some extra totals like a percent based on the data in a certain column. Here's my query:

```
SELECT
       ADV.Account
       ADV.City
       ADV.LocationID
       NUR.QueryID
       NUR.Response
FROM ADV.Visits ADV
LEFT JOIN NUR.Responses  NUR   ON (NUR.VisitID  = ADV.VisitID AND
                                   NUR.SourceID = ADV.SourceID )
WHERE NUR.QueryID = '1' AND
NUR.DateTime BETWEEN "x" AND "y" AND
ADV.LocationID IN ('1stFloor', '2ndFloor', 'ICU')
```

Here is an example of my responses

```
AccountNumber   City    LocationID  QueryID Response
12345         JAMESTOWN    ICU          1      Y
13254         JAMESTOWN    ICU          1      N
13584         SIMCITY    1stFloor       1      Y
18789         JAMESTOWN  1stFloor       1      N
45678         JAMESTOWN  1stFloor       1      Y
56789         CITYSCAPE  1stFloor       1      Y
48971         JAMESTOWN  1stFloor       1      Y
457895        CITYSCAPE  1stFloor       1      Y
```

Below is what the matrix looks like in SSRS. I have it totaling based on the Y (Yes) or N (No) Responses and a full total at the bottom. I now want to (In the red box) put an expression that will give me the percentage of N Responses. I have tried this a dozen different ways including adding a separate table to do the expression, adding two different data sets, one keying on the Y responses and one on the N and putting them in separate matrices and then trying to do the arithmetic in a third table by referencing either ReportItems!TextBox.Value's or the Aggregate Values themselves but I continue to get a myriad of errors.

[image]

As I said originally, I don't know if it's my query that needs editing, the SSRS expression that I just can't get correct, or both. But ANY help would be appreciated! I am using SQLServer2008 (writing out of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio), and ReportBuilder3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this in your sql procedure result set and simply use `=MAX(myPercentCalc!Value,"myDataset"),` however, I would try to use a calc field for this. Calculated fields can be added to the dataset via the IDE where the list of dataset fields are simply add a new one and the value set as an expression so you could do a CALCNCount and set the expression to:

```
=IIF(myYNField!Value="N",1,0)
```

Then simply use the `SUM(CALCNCount!Value)` in your percentage calc.

Comment: Remember the part where I'm new to this? :-) I was able to to the Calculated Field (which I creatively called "CalculatedField" and set the value as the expression you gave but at that point I'm pretty lost.

Comment: The value will virtually be a field in your dataset. So, for each record in your datset, the expression will be evaluated. From there you use a calculated field like other fields, you make aggregate calculations such as sum, count, max and min. You probably need to place an expression that uses your calc field SUMMED value divided by the COUNT of the records in your dataset. The SUM(Field!Value,"DatasetName") would apply where the SUM if for all values in your DataSetName dataset.

Comment: Thank you! It took me a bit to work it out but now it makes sense and it worked! How have I never come across Calculated Fields? They are definitely going to be my savior from now on. Now that it clicked in my brain your original answer is perfect. Thanks again!